# Ansible creates DNS records in FreeIPA differently than when they're created manually

Tags: dns, ansible, freeipa

I've found that Ansible creates DNS records differently than when I create them manually; particularly when creating the Reverse DNS records (PTR). I'm running Ansible version 2.9.27 on Rocky Linux version 8.5.

Let's say, for example, I manually add a DNS record for a machine called "MyTest" with an IP address of 100.99.97.7 from the Identity Management console and check the box for it to create a reverse record as well.  And then from a separate machine in the domain (mts.sys) I use "dig -x 100.99.97.7" to perform a reverse lookup. It'll receive "MyTest.mts.sys" in the resulting answer.  Which is the desired outcome.

If instead I use Ansible to create the DNS records, then I have to use two Ansible tasks to accomplish it.  The first task is to create the basic A record and the second task is to add the PTR record to the Reverse DNS zone.  Here's what the two tasks look like at the moment:

```
- name: MyTest.mts.sys forward
  ipa_dnsrecord:
    ipa_pass: <password-redacted>
    ipa_user: <user-redacted>
    zone_name: mts.sys
    record_name: MyTest
    record_type: 'A'
    record_value: 100.99.97.7
    state: present

- name: MyTest.mts.sys reverse
  ipa_dnsrecord:
    ipa_pass: <password-redacted>
    ipa_user: <user-redacted>
    zone_name: 97.99.100.in-addr.arpa
    record_name: '7'
    record_type: 'PTR'
    record_value: 'MyTest'
    state: present
```

After running those two tasks, I can confirm that the records are created by viewing them in Identity Manager.  They appear; as far as I can tell, exactly the same as if I'd created them manually.  However, if I use the same command as before; "dig -x 100.99.97.7" then the answer comes back as "MyTest.mts.sys.97.99.100.in-addr-arpa".  When this occurs, it prevents me from being able to successfully install Foreman at a later stage of my playbook.

What would be the correct way to create DNS records (A and PTR) in FreeIPA using Ansible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible or not, the PTR value should be `'MyTest.mts.sys.'` (suffixed with a `.`) otherwise it will always have the zone name appended to it by DNS servers.

Comment: Wow! That did it. All I had to do was adjust the second ansible task to be "record_value: 'MyTest.mts.sys.'. It now resolves correctly. Thank you!!!